# Cordova i18n App Name

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

Currently I am working on a multilingual cordova App for iOS and Android. I am managing all i18n stuff with javascript, what is working quite well. The only thing left is the App name (What is displayed on the home screen) in the `config.xml` file. 
I try to keep my code as clean as possible. Currently my platforms-folder is in `.gitignore`, so I would really like to avoid changing stuff in the platforms folder directly. Is there any solution available? Or do I really have to write a cordova plugin for this?

Thanks in advance for your answers.
Cheers!